# Are the new Admin API scopes are supported in Google Apps Marketplace

Tags: google-apps, google-apps-marketplace, google-admin-sdk

We are using [Provisioning API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/provisioning/#retrieving_all_users_in_a_domain)'s(Readonly Scope) in Google Marketplace. We want to move to new [Directory API's](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/guides) as they the older API's are getting deprecated. I couldn't find anywhere whether these new scopes are supported in Google Marketplace Manifest.

Are these new API's supported in marketplace app manifest.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just need to turn Admin SDK on underneath the "Register Additional Profiles" page (which links to the API Console for your project) from the Vendor Profile page. You'll still need to perform 2-legged OAuth authentication to gain access.

Comment: I am working on an app that will be placed in the marketplace. Does that mean the app won't be able to pull the users in the console except the logged in person is an Administrator?